# sample n random permutations of a list in python

Tags: python, random, shuffle

I have a list of values such as:

```
lst = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

and I need to *reproducibly* return *n* random shuffles of this list.

Ideally, I need a function with seed such that `f(lst, samples = 2, seed = 1234)`
-> return two shuffles of the list `lst` such as:

```
[5, 7, 1, 6, 2, 8, 0, 4, 3, 9]
[8, 7, 3, 0, 1, 4, 5, 9, 6, 2]
```

Repeated execution of this function (with the same seed) would return the same two lists.

Comment: what have  you tried?

Comment: @Ade_1 I've tried some np, sklearn tools, and itertools.permutations. The problem is that i need the n shuffles. np and sklearn return just one shuffle. itertools return all permutations which is an overkill and I ran out of memory if the input list is long.

Comment: have you tried using the random library?

Comment: @tevemadar no, because it doesn't generate n shuffles. A single reproducible shuffle isn't a problem.

Comment: @user2743931 Then produce a single one n times?

Comment: @Ade_1, yes, basically the same problem as with np. The issue is generating *n* shuffles.

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode and can I seed that? I need reproducible shuffles

Comment: @user2743931 Of course you can. Just do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `np.copy`

```
import numpy as np

lst = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]


def shuffle_list(arr:list,samples:int,seed:int):
    np.random.seed(seed)
    res = []
    for i in range(samples):
        arr_copy=np.copy(arr)
        np.random.shuffle(arr_copy)
        res.append(arr_copy)
    return res


#test
print(shuffle_list(lst,2,1234))
```

output:

```
[array([7, 2, 9, 1, 0, 8, 4, 5, 6, 3]), array([7, 3, 5, 1, 4, 8, 0, 2, 6, 9])]
```

Comment: this looks good, thanks! I didn't know the seed can be applied to generate random but reproducible shuffles in a for loop

Comment: @user2743931 because you didn't even look at the duplicate.

Comment: @joostblack, meet [`random.sample()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample)

Answer (score 1):

This works without `numpy`:

```
import sys
import random

some_seed = 123  # change this to get different shuffles

def n_shuffles(lst, n):
    r = random.Random(some_seed)
    for _ in range(n):
        _l = lst[:]
        r.shuffle(_l)
        yield _l


l = list(range(10))
>>> [*n_shuffles(l, 3)]
[[8, 7, 5, 9, 2, 3, 6, 1, 4, 0], [7, 6, 3, 4, 1, 0, 2, 5, 9, 8], [1, 8, 5, 6, 4, 7, 9, 0, 2, 3]]
>>> [*n_shuffles(l, 3)]
[[8, 7, 5, 9, 2, 3, 6, 1, 4, 0], [7, 6, 3, 4, 1, 0, 2, 5, 9, 8], [1, 8, 5, 6, 4, 7, 9, 0, 2, 3]]
```

Comment: By seeding with a different seed before each shuffle, the thought is to reduce the likelihood of having repeated identical shuffles. But probably the difference is negligible for all but the most trivial inputs.

Comment: True, it is quite unnecessary. Removed the double seeding.

Comment: Nah, that's because of the `random.random()` line you have there which consumes one random number and changes the state of the `Random` object.

Comment: Ok, using an independent `Random` object now to keep it a generator.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it wasn't an *exact* duplicate, but the proposed topic has pretty much shown that re-setting the `seed()` is the key:

```
import random

def shuffles(l,n):
  random.seed(4) # just the same one as in the referred topic
  return [random.sample(l,k=len(l)) for i in range(n)]

print(shuffles([1,2,3,4],3))
print("again:")
print(shuffles([1,2,3,4],3))
```

will generate

> ```
> [[2, 4, 1, 3], [4, 1, 3, 2], [1, 2, 3, 4]]                            
> again:                                                                
> [[2, 4, 1, 3], [4, 1, 3, 2], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
> ```